# How to put database information as headers in table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want some information that is stored in my database to be an header in a table.

Basically its got a list of competitors down the side with theirs scores running in rows. Each competitor has their own row. At the top of the table is the name of the event they took part in. I cant manage to make the event name come from the database so got to edit the page each time I add a set of scores.

I have attempted as you will see in the code below;

```
<?php
require("db_connect.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, (ct1 + ct2 + ct3 + ct4 + ct5 + ct6) AS results FROM resultsopen WHERE ct='1'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { echo 'No competitors found'; } else {

echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\" align=\"center\">
        <tr align=\"center\">
        <td>Competitor</td>
        <td>Member No</td>
        <td>" . $row['cta'] . "</td>
        <td>E2</td>
        <td>E3</td>
        <td>E4</td>
        <td>E5</td>
        <td>E6</td>
        <td>E7</td>
        <td>Overall</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>";

$x=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    if($x%2): $rowbgcolor = "#FFFFFF"; else: $rowbgcolor = "#EEEEEE"; endif;
    echo "<tr align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"" .$rowbgcolor. "\">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['competitor'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['memberno'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ct1'] . "</td>";
```

The line in question is `<td>" . $row['cta'] . "</td>`

The other lines are just text which I manually change each time.

I also know that mysql should be changed to mysqli but I am not confident in the change just yet.

Comment: $row['cta'] is not yet defined - $row only gets defined in your while loop.

Comment: you could do a `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` before the headings, and then a [`mysql_data_seek($result, 0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) before your rows loop to reset the pointer back to the 1st returned row.